# Is it possible to implement a touch listener/handler without using an external library in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, listeners

I am trying to implement a touch interface on a 3D graph to allow the user to rotate it on a touch-based device, however I'm not exactly sure how to do it. The code in placed for the rotation of the 3D graph does not use listeners, but rather directly calls certain functions for the rotations.

If I add regular mouse listeners and handlers, would tablet based browsers be able to interpret a user's touch inputs as mouse inputs?

If not, is there an easy way to implement touch controls without using an external library such as JQuery Mobile?

Comment: ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Touch_events )

( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/TouchEvent )

Touch events do exist, and I've used them quite a lot. I'm not sure how to tell you how to implement them without more detail though

Comment: Touch events are derived from click events + motion. Start with click and work your way up.

Comment: So in essence, implement actual mouse listeners and handlers first? 

also thank you Llepwryd for the links